# Cohen-Macaulay versus shellable simplicial complexes

Tags: co.combinatorics

There are some discussion of shellable simplicial complexes here 
[Testing simplicial complexes for shellability](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121371/testing-simplicial-complexes-for-shellability). My question is the following:

Assume that $\Delta$ is a pure simplicial complex on a finite vertex set $V$. Assume that $\Delta$ is Cohen-Macaulay, i.e., it has at most top-dimensional homology. (There are examples of CM but non-shellable simplicial complexes). Moreover, assume that the symmetric group $S_V$ acts transitively on $\Delta$. Could this possibly imply that the simplicial complex $\Delta$ is shellable?

Comment: What do you mean by "the symmetric group $S_V$ acts transitively on $\Delta$"? Do you mean that the automorphism group of $\Delta$ acts transitively on $V$?

Comment: Yes, the automorphism group of $\Delta$ does act transitively on $\Delta$. But maybe something stronger than that, but I'm not sure how to phrase it. An example that I have in mind is the matching complex of a complete graph.

Comment: Take care that you want also links of faces to have at most top homology for Cohen-Macaulayness.

Comment: If $S_V$ acts transitively on $\Delta$, then I suppose $\Delta$ is some skeleton of a simplex, hence shellable.  But that's almost surely not what you have in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dissertation of Frank Lutz
(http://page.math.tu-berlin.de/~lutz/dissertation.ps‎) has examples of
Cohen-Macaulay vertex-transitive simplicial complexes that are not
shellable. In particular, there is such a triangulation of Poincaré
dodecahedral space $X$ with 17 vertices. This triangulation is
Cohen-Macaulay since $X$ is a topological 3-manifold with the same
homology groups as a 3-sphere. It is not shellable because it is not
simply-connected.

Comment: Why does simply-connected imply not shellable? Isn't the boundary of the triangle shellable, but not simply-connected?

Comment: I said that "it is not shellable because it is **not** simply-connected." A shellable manifold is simply-connected (and in fact must be a sphere if it without boundary and a ball otherwise),

Comment: Yeah, typo on my part. I meant "Why does not simply-connected imply not shellable"

Comment: Every shellable simplicial complex has the homotopy type of a wedge of spheres. I don't have access to a reference at the moment.